# How to automatically add administration fee to open invoice after date_due has passed?

Tags: odoo

Can anyone help me to automatically add a fee to an open invoice after date_due has passed? I for example set an admin fee in res.company which is called when invoices are pass the due date.

Regards,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

If you want it automatically then add a `scheduler`. The scheduler function should search for all open invoice after due date and add new invoice line with the administration fee or add the administration fee to the existing invoice line.
For example, Below is a data xml you can use to create the scheduler.
XML Part

```
<record forcecreate="True" id="ir_cron_auto_invoice_scheduler_action" model="ir.cron">
    <field name="name">Run Automatic Invoice scheduler</field>
    <field eval="True" name="active"/>
    <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
    <field name="interval_number">1</field>
    <field name="interval_type">days</field>
    <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
    <field eval="True" name="doall"/>
    <field eval="'your.model.name'" name="model"/><!--here it is account.invoice-->
    <field eval="'automatic_invoice_scheduler'" name="function"/>
    <!--its a new function in account.invoice model-->
    <!-- from which you can search all the invoices and what you need-->
    <field eval="'(False,)'" name="args"/>
</record>
```

Python part

```
#Its just a example function.make necessary changes
#Inherit the account_invoice and add the function
import time
def automatic_invoice_scheduler(self, cr, uid, ids,context=None):
    ids = self.search(cr, uid,[('date_invoice','<=',time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),('state','open'),('due_added','=',False)], context=context)
    #due added is a new field you have to add so that once the due
    # is added then its invoice id is not added in the scheduler
    ###########################
    #Add your code here.add the due_fees to the invoice lines
    #write the due_added boolean field to true
    ###########################
    return True
```

Comment: Im trying to use a function any ideas?

Comment: Thanks OmaL, do you have an example of a function? I'm a bit confused as to how to proceed. Where do I add the xml?